# Как получить значения из формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется форма, в этой форме есть `chekbox-Ы` со значением, а также другие `input`:

Как мне получить значения только активированных `chekbox-ОВ` и остальных `input-ов` и  отправить все эти данные с использованием `ajax`?

Такой код не работает:

```js
var data = $('#myform').serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'data_form.php',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    $('#page_ajax').html(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr, str) {
    alert('Ajax error');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myform' method='post'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="123">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="456">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="789">
  <input type="text" name="my_name" value="Oleg">
</form>
```

Comment: А код обработчика формы можете приложить? Без этого мало что понятно, потому что вроде как всё правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Страница с формой:

```
<form id='myform' method='post'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="123">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="456">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="789">
    <input type="text" name="my_name" value="Oleg">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id='page_ajax'></div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#myform').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/data_form.php',
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#page_ajax').html(data);
          },
          error: function(xhr, str) {
            alert('Ajax error');
          }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Файл `data_form.php` для проверки:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Comment: Это ответ или дополнение к вопросу?

Comment: Ответ. Внес небольшие правки в код автора. Код выполняет поставленную задачу